# PhoneGap 2.0 doesn't show console.log in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Using a basic PhoneGap 2.0 app, I don't see any `console.log` messages in XCode. I read that Release builds shouldn't relay the log, but it seems to have built CordovaLib in Debug mode as I do see messages from `PluginResult`.

Is the logging functionality still supposed to be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in my app that is using phonegap2.0. However, one thing I noticed is that it only starts working after 'deviceready' is fired. May be worth taking a look.