# console.log not working in an iOS PhoneGap 3.0 app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am upgrading an app from PhoneGap 1.9 to PhoneGap 3.0. The console.log() function is not working anymore. Previously, the ouput was written in the XCode console. What's the best way to restore the logging feature?

I have read: [PhoneGap 2.0 doesn't show console.log in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292177/phonegap-2-0-doesnt-show-console-log-in-xcode) but in PhoneGap 3.0 console.log does not work even after the deviceReady event.

I am also interested to see the javascript errors directly in xcode.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need the debug console plugin added to your project:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
```

In later versions of phonegap/cordova, to add the debug console plugin in your project:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console`

Comment: Does it work out of the box for you? I do not get any additional log in my xcode console.

Comment: Yep all i needed was to install that plugin and i was able to see my console.logs in xcode

Comment: It works in a hello world project but not in my real app project. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you able to see syntax or any errors in the xcode console? Even in the HelloWorld, I cannot see the errors in the console.

Comment: I'm getting the error "[error] project directory could not be found". Anyone know what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: As long as your script tag to phonegap.js is above the `console.log(..)` line you should be fine.

Comment: We added the plugin and ensure phonegap.js is above any calls to "console.log" but still nothing appears in Xcode. Any clues?

Comment: I ran into this issue as well, with phonegap's new implementation you need to add your javascript content after `app.Initialize();` When a new page is navigated too, phonegap actually appends to the start page's <body> (index.html, normally) so any code you may have in the <head> tags will be ignored.

Comment: it's looking for a file that doesn't exist "The file “CDVLogger.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Answer (score 30):

It turned out, at least in my case, that `deviceready` function for the logger was not getting called. The final line in `logger.js`.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", logger.__onDeviceReady, false);
```

The solution (or really a work-around) is to call the `logger.__onDeviceReady` function from your `deviceready` listener function:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (window.cordova.logger) {
        window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: My problem was - it worked in a HelloWorld project, but not after I merged my "www" folder code from my (master) Android project. Your solution saved me!

Comment: This fixed my broken console.log as well.

Comment: This fixed my problem with console.log too.

Answer (score 9):

I've found [JSconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com) **extremely** useful for remotely capturing console logs from mobile devices.

Heres how you set it up:

1. In you apps index.html, Include(change the ID):

   ```
     <script src="http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?<MAKE UP SOME UNIQUE ID>"></script>
   ```
2. On your computer, Go to jsconsole.com and type `:listen <YOUR UNIQUE ID>`

Open your app on your mobile device, you will see console logs on your computer.

Comment: I can't include a script from another domain. Any help? (please send link)

Answer (score 6):

Add the console plugin as in the Sam's answer and **ensure to include cordova.js** on every page otherwise no plugin works.

When using phonegap plugins I was adding phonegap.js in script tag then I noticed that plugins (any) works on index.html page only. When I changed phonegap.js to cordova.js, plugins(notification, camera etc) started working on rest of the pages. If this helps anyone.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed the Cordova console-plug-in, then when you run your app:

```
phonegap run iOS
```

you will find the logs at:

```
[your project dir]/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

for IOS. All console logs show up as expected.

Comment: I did nor find the file console.log, when I try to re-install the plugin i get "already installed, 'sall good"

Comment: For @Cherif 's comment awhile ago (in case someone else is coming here), you'll have to run rm plugin command and also for configuration issues this thread ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/23934073/955861 ) is good and helped me solve my build error after installing the plugin. Run the rm command <code>cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console</code> and try to run the install again. If you have build errors again look at the other SO thread.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

The following or a similar error message occurs when adding the console plugin to the ios platform (or after reinstalling) via Command-line Interface:

> **"CDVPlugin class CDVLogger (pluginName: Console) does not exist."**

**Solution**

Open your Xcode project and go to the tab "Build Phases". Now open the drop-down named "Compile Sources". Click on the "+" sign at the end of the list and add "CDVLogger.m" or any other missing source.

Answer (score 3):

Besides adding the Console plugin I have another assumption why it might not work:

console.log in Phonegap is called asynchronously thus if a future call fails, the whole function fails and all log calls within are swallowed.

```
  receivedEvent = function( id ) {
    alert( 'This message is displayed because alert is called synchronously ')
    console.log( 'This will not be displayed in Phonegap only in browser' )
    callingAFunctionWhichDoesNotExist()
    console.log( 'This will neither be displayed in Phonegap nor in browser' )
  }
```

Comment: This corresponds to what I am seeing. This makes it really hard to debug. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) really useful. Unlike anything else [cough cough weinre], it let's you console log from your local app